# How to define the font-family name in the URL to the SVG font?

Tags: css, svg, webfonts

The recommended code for including webfonts seems to be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my_font';
    src: url('my-font.eot');
    src: url('my-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('my-font.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('my-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('my-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('my-font.svg#my_font') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

As you may note, the name given to the font family is repeated in the URL pointing to the SVG font:

```
font-family: 'my_font';                    <= "my_font"
url('my-font.svg#my_font') format('svg');  <= "my_font"
```

Now I don't like my font name to be lowercase and including an underscore. I want it to be "My Font":

```
font-family: 'My Font';
```

**But then, how do I need to define the font-family name in the SVG url?**

```
url('my-font.svg#My Font') format('svg');
url('my-font.svg#My%20Font') format('svg');
url('my-font.svg#my_font') format('svg');
```

And what is the purpose of the font-family name in that URL anyway?

---

After asking this question, I learned that:

a. [TTF](http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf) and [WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff) are supported by all current browsers except Opera Mini (and [Opera Mini doesn't support SVG fonts either](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20fonts)), so no current browser needs SVG fonts.

b. [Fonts have been dropped from the SVG2.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/changes.html) in September 2015.

I have therefore removed SVG fonts from my websites and deleted the relevant line from the code given as a sample above. As a result, my question is outdated and no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRI scheme used in `url('my-font.svg#my_font')` is called a [`funcIRI`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/types.html#DataTypeFuncIRI) and it's actually pointing to the element which has the id `my_font` inside the `my-font.svg` document.

I think you can name your font however you want in the `font-family` property, as long as your are pointing to the correct font IRI in the `src` one.

(In case of an SVG font, it needs to be pointing to a [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/font) element.)

The [SVG fonts tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts) on the Mozilla Developer Network provides the following example:

```
<font id="Super_Sans">
  <!-- and so on -->
</font>

<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-family: "Super Sans";
  src: url(#Super_Sans);
}
</style>

<text font-family="Super Sans">My text uses Super Sans</text>
```